# Force system to enter Advanced Boot Options menu

Tags: windows, boot

I’m trying to force my system to show the Advanced Boot Options menu at startup. Do you have any idea how can I do that using other method than F8 before Windows loads ? 
In other words, I’d like to set that command, restart my system and the Advanced Boot Options menu to be shown without user pressing F8.

Comment: Flagged this question for migration to a more appropriate site, as it's not programming-related. Hopefully that'll happen when more people see it and agree with me. In the meantime, find your answer here: http://www.nextofwindows.com/3-ways-to-fire-up-windows-8-advanced-boot-options/

Comment: Care to share what version of Windows you talking about?